# Simple level design in Javascript: How to ask user if they want to continue the game after Nth questions?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa game in javascript for the first time as practice.

Players guess an animal after a clue is given.

I want to give the option after the 6th (or however long) question if the player wants to keep playing.

For example, I have 30 questions of all the same level, but want to have 5 levels (or rounds really). So I want to ask after the 6th question before they move onto the next level.

Here is my current code which does not have the counter, it just keeps going until the questions run out.

I know python you could keep a counter and check when it gets to a certain number, however, I'm still new javascript and coding in general. Any  suggests on what I should do would be appreciated.

```
function nextAnimal(handlerInput) {
    var speakOutput = ""
    
    //if the previous guess was correct, respond postively
    if(getAnimalIndex(handlerInput) >= 0) {
        if(isGuessCorrect(handlerInput)) { //skip the first animal
            speakOutput += generatePositiveResponse();
        }
    }
    
    //increment animalIndex
    incrementAnimalIndex(handlerInput)
    var currAnimal = getCurrAnimal(handlerInput)
    
    //check if index has reached MAX_ANIMALS
    if(getAnimalIndex(handlerInput) === MAX_ANIMALS) {
        setGameState(handlerInput, "askingActions") //move on to actions
        return nextAction(handlerInput)
    } else {
        //ask the next animal
        speakOutput += currAnimal.question
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(currentAnimal.hint)
            .withShouldEndSession(false)
            .withStandardCard(currentAnimal.cardTitle, currAnimal.cardContent, currAnimal.image)
            .getResponse();
    }
}


//move on to the next action in the game 
function nextAction(handlerInput) {
    var speakOutput = ""
    
    //if the previous guess was correct, respond positively
    if(getActionIndex(handlerInput) >= 0) { //skip the first action
        if(isGuessCorrect(handlerInput)) {
            speakOutput += generatePositiveResponse();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it's Python or JS, the first thing to understand is that each interaction with the customer is a different run of your script (especially with Lambda). So your counter needs to be stored between interactions. The easiest way to do that is using the Alexa SDK's built in session store.

You pull the values, like so. If it's the start of the session and you haven't stored anything it'll be an empty object.

```js
var session_vars = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
```

You can add whatever attributes you want as properties of the object.

```js
session_vars.counter = 1;
```

Each time the player answers a question, add 1 to it. Then store it.

```js
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(session_vars);
```

If you want to store between sessions, use the persistent attributes adapters.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html